# Create Docker volume with preexisting data in it

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have a MySQL image that I launch a container from.
I set up dbs , import sql-dump files and create users every time the container is created.

When I work on the container I create various data that are stored in MySQL.

I would like to save these extra data in a data volume container [DVC] so I could give the DVC to a colleague and continue from where I stopped.

The thing is that he will also launch a MySQL container and the initial procedure will be repeated from scratch.

As I have read, if I mount [`--volumes-from`] the volumes [`/etc/mysql` and `/var/lib/mysql`] from the DVC , the already existing data will be covered and will not be readable.

Is it possible to use volumes with directories that already have data in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, but that's because you've gone down the wrong road with your container.

This is why your image *shouldn't* include static data. Keep the static things in the image, and they dynamic things in a data container. (And a startup script to dynamically evaluate anything that needs it)

You can probably use a `docker cp` to extract the files into a data container for a one off - or just passthrough mount a local filesystem, to a new mountpoint, and just use `tar` / `rsync` with `docker exec` before re-mounting - but actually I'd suggest rebuild your image to always use a data container for it's data.

Comment: I think I could restructure my image , as I understood , by mounting the volume container BEFORE I create anything , and all data [initial and new] will reside in the data container. Then I can share the DVC and someone else can pick up from where I stopped. I think that , that way it would be a matter of decision ,when using a docker-compose file, whether to use a new DVC or an existing one. Correct?

Comment: Yes. That would do it.