# Docker & Angular 2 : binded directory remains empty

Tags: angular, docker, mean-stack, docker-volume

I have to work on a MEAN stack application, entirely dockerised.
So we have three images:

- One for the mongo database
- One for the backend (nodejs)
- And one for the frontend (angular 2)

As I want to work on the front while the container is running, I'm trying to bind a folder to the src folder in the container.

To do so I run the container with the following command :

```
docker run --name frontend -d -p 5555:5555 --link backend -v /home/frontend:/code/src/ infra-frontend:latest
```

Docker create the directory, but it stay empty despite it is not empty in the container (I checked with the *docker exec bash* command).

So, as this is the first time I have to deal with Docker, I am a little bit lost, and I would like to have some help.

Comment: Is docker running directly on your host, or inside something like VirtualBox?

Comment: Directly on my host, why ?

Comment: when you share a volume in the container it will replace the folder in the container with the folder in the host, so if the folder is not something that your container will fill it will remain empty.

This question can complement it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152081/create-docker-volume-with-preexisting-data-in-it?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Docker volume with preexisting data in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36152081/create-docker-volume-with-preexisting-data-in-it)

Comment: It seems to be the same problem, but I don't really understand the answer.

Answer (score 3):

*NOTE: This question is answered by [Create Docker volume with preexisting data in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36152439/2127492) previous question, but since the user is having some difficulty understanding what this might mean, I have added details below.*

When docker is mounting volumes it follows the rules of [mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) for the unix filesystem.  This means that those files are not going to show up when you mount.  You can actually read more about this in the Github Issues for docker [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4361).

The way I see it you have a couple of options:

1. Read up on "data-only containers" and use this (probably better to look at Docker Volume)
2. Use the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` to specify a script that will download the source to `/code/src/` on startup of the container.
3. Keep the source always on host, and just point to it from the docker image (e.g. /home/frontend <- has data, empty dir -> /code/src/)
4. Download the source to `/code/src` but expose the volume `/mycode/`.  Then sync changes between `/code/src/` and `/mycode` using something like [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)

Each of those options has varying levels of difficulty.  The easiest by far is probably #2 or #3.  The concept of data-only containers is I believe replaced by [`docker volume`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/) since Docker 1.10 ish?

Answer (score 2):

Previous explanation from @jrbeverly is probably right but not so easy to understand and not related to docker documentation.

Here is the simple explanation from Docker documentation :

"Volumes are initialized when a container is created. If the container’s base image contains data at the specified mount point, that existing data is copied into the new volume upon volume initialization. (**Note that this does not apply when mounting a host directory**.)"

source : https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/

So you could create a named volume (-v frontend:/code/src) if you need /code/src content to be copied into the volume upon volume initialization. Your volume won't be in /home/frontend but in /var/lib/docker/volumes/frontend/_data.